# Laravel collection paginate with where clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have a news table and i manage the read or unread flag. so I want to paginate both flags are separate without additional database queries. 
My requirement is to get all the news and filter read or unread and paginate for a separate table view.
Once I try the following code but getting an error `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.`

```
    $ns=News::all();
    $ns->where('read',1)->paginate(2);
    $ns->where('read',0)->paginate(2);
```

I want to do that using only one DB Query.

Comment: Your method is wrong.  Try this  `$ns = News::where('read', 1)->paginate(2);`

Comment: Try below code
$readns = News::where('read',1)->paginate(2);
$unreadns = News::where('read',0)->paginate(2);

Comment: @TalhaF. the query is correct without paginate function. I want to know, how to paginate collection with where clause.

Comment: Since you have a collection you Can use slice. $ns->where('read',1)->splice($index, $howMany); There you must manage some sort of counter to get through all records but is an ideea.

Answer (score 2):

Can you Try below code

```
$readns = News::where('read',1)->paginate(2);
$unreadns = News::where('read',0)->paginate(2);
```

You can use chunk() for it. Check this one [laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#chunking-results](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#chunking-results)

Comment: No. I want to do with only one query. read the question carefully

Comment: No. How can I do?

Comment: Check this one https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#chunking-results

Comment: It does not fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel paginate can't make a pagination from collection, you need eloquent query builder instead.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results

So, if you still want make a pagination from collection, you can create custom pagination for collection with macro. An example is in this gist :

https://gist.github.com/simonhamp/549e8821946e2c40a617c85d2cf5af5e

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add it to helpers

```
function paginate($items, $perPage = 15, $page = null, $options = []) {
    $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
    $items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);
    return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, $options);
});
```

Usage:

```
$ns = News::all();
$ns1 = paginate((clone $ns)->where('read', 1), 2);
$ns2 = paginate((clone $ns)->where('read', 0), 2);
```

Comment: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.